# Keep (some) reputation when answer is unaccepted after a long time

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

You post an answer which is accepted.

Although kind of a workaround, it might be the best possible answer.
After a longer period of time, another (better) answer is posted and accepted instead of your answer which becomes unaccepted.

Now you lose 15 rep although you have provided a good solution for a while.

**Wouldn't it be nicer to keep some reputation points

if an answer had been accepted for a long time?**

I thought of something like:

```
unaccepted within 4 weeks  - lose 15 rep
unaccepted after  4 weeks  - lose 10 rep
unaccepted after  3 months - lose 5 rep
unaccepted after  6 months - keep all rep points
```

*Could be somewhat demotivating, when some of your posted workarounds become obsolete after months or years and you lose all the rep, although you provided a good solution for that long.*

Comment: what's with all the downvotes?

Comment: On meta it just means disagree since there is no real rep gained or lost here.

Comment: You perhaps don't appreciate the benefits of having the marked answer.  That post has been basking in the green cast glow for over two years.  Listed at the top, everybody read it first.  If it is a good answer and the google juice is flowing then it can get a lot of additional votes.  That didn't happen.  It has run its course, no more can be eked, pining for the fjords, it is a dead parrot.  And besides, rep calc is already grossly convoluted and they'll never go for it.  Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes answers *do* become obsolete, or there is a *better* answer posted.

Rep is rep.

It is nothing but **MaAaGiC** internet points.

We all learn to live with it and move on.

:-)

Let me know how I can transfer some to you (this includes anyone looking at this answer ;-) )

Comment: I want some! I really don't get how you guys end up with Ks of it!!! I struggle for 1K :) ... but I _think_ I can live without it...

Comment: @urban well i have been here for a while and have some old quality posts :-)

Comment: Maybe a feature request to developers may get this functionality. Rep Transfer.